# How to change Log Level of the MongoDB Java Driver?

Tags: java, mongodb, log4j, slf4j, mongodb-java

I want to remove the logging output of the insert log messages (org.mongodb.driver.protocol.insert). How do I do that?

I stumbled across some stackoverflow posts but they didn't work for me. I have tried running these method calls in the class initializer method of the class that will load the MongoDB driver class:

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE);

org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver.protocol.insert").setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.ERROR);
```

as well as setting the following properties in the class initializer of my class that will load the MongoDB driver class.

```
System.setProperty("DEBUG.MONGO", "false");
System.setProperty("DB.TRACE", "false");
```

and creating a log4j.properties

```
log4j.logger.org.mongodb.driver=ERROR
#log4j.logger.com.mongodb=ERROR <- tried this too even though it should be outdated
log4j.rootLogger=error, stdout
```

but all to no avail. The messages still get printed for every insert to the console:

```
02:00:32.619 [main] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.insert - Inserting 1 documents into namespace x.data on connection [connectionId{localValue:5}] to server x:27017
02:00:32.622 [main] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.insert - Insert completed
02:00:32.622 [main] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.insert - Inserting 1 documents into namespace x.data on connection [connectionId{localValue:4}] to server x:27017
02:00:32.625 [main] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.insert - Insert completed
```

What's the right way to stop the logging of those messages?

*MongoDB Driver version 3.3.0*